What's the rationale behind Africa/Freetown being UTC-00:53 in PHP?
What's going on with PHP's definition of the Africa/Freetown time zone? Starting in 1941, every 31 December it changes to XXX UTC+00:40, then immediately (the same second) changes back to LMT UTC-00:53 (Local Mean Time). I've tried searching for a time zone of UTC-00:53 and the time zone for Africa/Freetown but I couldn't find anything even mentioning it, much less explaining it. Freetown appears to be the time zone for all of Sierra Leone (UTC+00:00). It also appears that Africa/Freetown is not a canonical time zone. Is it included in the canonical time zones by mistake?
Data in YAML format
- ts: -9223372036854775808
  time: "-292277022657-01-27T08:29:52+0000"
  offset: -3180
  isdst: false
  abbr: LMT
- ts: -2776979220
  time: "1882-01-01T00:53:00+0000"
  offset: -3180
  isdst: false
  abbr: FMT
- ts: -1783120020
  time: "1913-07-01T00:53:00+0000"
  offset: -3600
  isdst: false
  abbr: "-01"
- ts: -1170284400
  time: "1932-12-01T01:00:00+0000"
  offset: -2400
  isdst: true
  abbr: "-0040"
- ts: -1159831200
  time: "1933-04-01T00:40:00+0000"
  offset: -3600
  isdst: false
  abbr: "-01"
- ts: -1146610800
  time: "1933-09-01T01:00:00+0000"
  offset: -2400
  isdst: true
  abbr: "-0040"
- ts: -1128295200
  time: "1934-04-01T00:40:00+0000"
  offset: -3600
  isdst: false
  abbr: "-01"
- ...
- ts: -957308400
  time: "1939-09-01T01:00:00+0000"
  offset: -2400
  isdst: true
  abbr: "-0040"
- ts: -956964000
  time: "1939-09-05T00:40:00+0000"
  offset: -3600
  isdst: false
  abbr: "-01"
- ts: -885769200
  time: "1941-12-07T01:00:00+0000"
  offset: 1200
  isdst: true
  abbr: "+01"
- ts: -883615200
  time: "1941-12-31T23:20:00+0000"
  offset: 2400
  isdst: false
  abbr: XXX
- ts: -883615200
  time: "1941-12-31T23:20:00+0000"
  offset: -3180
  isdst: false
  abbr: LMT
- ts: -852079200
  time: "1942-12-31T23:20:00+0000"
  offset: 2400
  isdst: false
  abbr: XXX
- ts: -852079200
  time: "1942-12-31T23:20:00+0000"
  offset: -3180
  isdst: false
  abbr: LMT
- ...
- ts: 2145914400
  time: "2037-12-31T23:20:00+0000"
  offset: 2400
  isdst: false
  abbr: XXX
- ts: 2145914400
  time: "2037-12-31T23:20:00+0000"
  offset: -3180
  isdst: false
  abbr: LMT

Code
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('Africa/Freetown');
var_dump($timezone->getTransitions());

Partial Output
array(214) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["ts"]=>
    int(-9223372036854775808)
    ["time"]=>
    string(33) "-292277022657-01-27T08:29:52+0000"
    ["offset"]=>
    int(-3180)
    ["isdst"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["abbr"]=>
    string(3) "LMT"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["ts"]=>
    int(-2776979220)
    ["time"]=>
    string(24) "1882-01-01T00:53:00+0000"
    ["offset"]=>
    int(-3180)
    ["isdst"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["abbr"]=>
    string(3) "FMT"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(5) {
    ["ts"]=>
    int(-1783120020)
    ["time"]=>
    string(24) "1913-07-01T00:53:00+0000"
    ["offset"]=>
    int(-3600)
    ["isdst"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["abbr"]=>
    string(3) "-01"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(5) {
    ["ts"]=>
    int(-1170284400)
    ["time"]=>
    string(24) "1932-12-01T01:00:00+0000"
    ["offset"]=>
    int(-2400)
    ["isdst"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["abbr"]=>
    string(5) "-0040"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(5) {
    ["ts"]=>
    int(-1159831200)
    ["time"]=>
    string(24) "1933-04-01T00:40:00+0000"
    ["offset"]=>
    int(-3600)
    ["isdst"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["abbr"]=>
    string(3) "-01"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(5) {
    ["ts"]=>
    int(-1146610800)
    ["time"]=>
    string(24) "1933-09-01T01:00:00+0000"
    ["offset"]=>
    int(-2400)
    ["isdst"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["abbr"]=>
    string(5) "-0040"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(5) {
    ["ts"]=>
    int(-1128295200)
    ["time"]=>
    string(24) "1934-04-01T00:40:00+0000"
    ["offset"]=>
    int(-3600)
    ["isdst"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["abbr"]=>
    string(3) "-01"
  }
.
.
.
  [17]=>
  array(5) {
    ["ts"]=>
    int(-957308400)
    ["time"]=>
    string(24) "1939-09-01T01:00:00+0000"
    ["offset"]=>
    int(-2400)
    ["isdst"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["abbr"]=>
    string(5) "-0040"
  }
  [18]=>
  array(5) {
    ["ts"]=>
    int(-956964000)
    ["time"]=>
    string(24) "1939-09-05T00:40:00+0000"
    ["offset"]=>
    int(-3600)
    ["isdst"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["abbr"]=>
    string(3) "-01"
  }
  [19]=>
  array(5) {
    ["ts"]=>
    int(-885769200)
    ["time"]=>
    string(24) "1941-12-07T01:00:00+0000"
    ["offset"]=>
    int(1200)
    ["isdst"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["abbr"]=>
    string(3) "+01"
  }
  [20]=>
  array(5) {
    ["ts"]=>
    int(-883615200)
    ["time"]=>
    string(24) "1941-12-31T23:20:00+0000"
    ["offset"]=>
    int(2400)
    ["isdst"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["abbr"]=>
    string(3) "XXX"
  }
  [21]=>
  array(5) {
    ["ts"]=>
    int(-883615200)
    ["time"]=>
    string(24) "1941-12-31T23:20:00+0000"
    ["offset"]=>
    int(-3180)
    ["isdst"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["abbr"]=>
    string(3) "LMT"
  }
  [22]=>
  array(5) {
    ["ts"]=>
    int(-852079200)
    ["time"]=>
    string(24) "1942-12-31T23:20:00+0000"
    ["offset"]=>
    int(2400)
    ["isdst"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["abbr"]=>
    string(3) "XXX"
  }
  [23]=>
  array(5) {
    ["ts"]=>
    int(-852079200)
    ["time"]=>
    string(24) "1942-12-31T23:20:00+0000"
    ["offset"]=>
    int(-3180)
    ["isdst"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["abbr"]=>
    string(3) "LMT"
  }
.
.
.
  [212]=>
  array(5) {
    ["ts"]=>
    int(2145914400)
    ["time"]=>
    string(24) "2037-12-31T23:20:00+0000"
    ["offset"]=>
    int(2400)
    ["isdst"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["abbr"]=>
    string(3) "XXX"
  }
  [213]=>
  array(5) {
    ["ts"]=>
    int(2145914400)
    ["time"]=>
    string(24) "2037-12-31T23:20:00+0000"
    ["offset"]=>
    int(-3180)
    ["isdst"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["abbr"]=>
    string(3) "LMT"
  }
}


Not sure what you mean by canonical timezone. It's the only timezone that is associated with Sierra Leone. Also you might have a bad timezone database, your output doesn't seem to match https://3v4l.org/nfEIY#v8.3.12

@apokryfos "SL Africa/Freetown  Link†
+00:00 +00:00 GMT backward Link to Africa/Abidjan" from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones. It's a link, so not canonical.

The answer can be found in the IANA timezone data. In the file backzone, the following is stated:
# Sierra Leone
# From P Chan (2020-12-09):
# Standard time of GMT-1 was adopted on 1913-07-01.  Twenty minutes of DST was
# introduce[d] in 1932 and was suspended in 1939.  In 1941, GMT was adopted by
# Defence Regulations.  This was made permanent in 1946.
#
# Government Notice No. 121 of 1913, 1913-06-06, Sierra Leone Royal Gazette,
# Vol. XLIV, No. 1384, 1913-06-14, p 347
# Alteration of Time Ordinance, 1932 (No. 34 of 1932) [1932-12-01]
# Alteration of Time (Amendment) Ordinance, 1938 (No. 25 of 1938) [1938-11-24]
# Defence Regulations (No. 9), 1939 (Regulations No. 9 of 1939), 1939-09-05
# Defence Regulations (No. 11), 1939 (Regulations No. 11 of 1939), 1939-09-27
# Defence (Amendment) (No. 17) Regulations, 1941 (Public Notice No. 157 of
# 1941), 1914-12-04
# Alteration of Time (Amendment) Ordinance, 1946 (No. 2 of 1946) [1946-02-07]

# From Tim Parenti (2021-03-02), per P Chan (2021-02-25):
# For Sierra Leone in 1957-1962, the standard time was defined in the
# Alteration of Time Ordinance, 1932 (as amended in 1946, renamed to Local Time
# Ordinance in 1960 and Local Time Act in 1961). It was unamended throughout
# that period.  See references to "Time" in the Alphabetical Index of the
# Legislation in force on the 31st day of December,
#   1957: https://books.google.com/books?id=lvQ-AQAAIAAJ&pg=RA2-PA49
#   1958: https://books.google.com/books?id=4fQ-AQAAIAAJ&pg=RA2-PA50
#   1959: https://books.google.com/books?id=p_U-AQAAIAAJ&pg=RA2-PA55
#   1960: https://books.google.com/books?id=JPY-AQAAIAAJ&pg=RA3-PA37
#   1961: https://books.google.com/books?id=7vY-AQAAIAAJ&pg=RA3-PA41
#   1962: https://books.google.com/books?id=W_c-AQAAIAAJ&pg=RA3-PA44
#   1963: https://books.google.com/books?id=9vk-AQAAIAAJ&pg=RA1-PA47
#
# Although Shanks & Pottenger had DST from Jun 1 00:00 to Sep 1 00:00 in this
# period, many contemporaneous almanacs agree that it wasn't used:
# https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz/2021-February/029866.html
# Go with the above.

Rule    SL  1932    only    -   Dec  1   0:00   0:20    -0040
Rule    SL  1933    1938    -   Mar 31  24:00   0   -01
Rule    SL  1933    1939    -   Aug 31  24:00   0:20    -0040
Rule    SL  1939    only    -   May 31  24:00   0   -01

Zone    Africa/Freetown -0:53:00 -  LMT 1882
            -0:53:00 -  FMT 1913 Jul  1 # Freetown MT
            -1:00   SL  %s  1939 Sep  5
            -1:00   -   -01 1941 Dec  6 24:00
             0:00   -   GMT

That file is full of other tweaks meant to try to reflect historical weirdness with certain timezones.
Note that there could still be oddities in PHPs interpretation itself, especially with something as esoteric as this.
Note also that "Local Mean Time" appears to be an indication that at some point the timezone was by default calculated by the locations longitude.
